# How to fix error "Process exited with error code 1" in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I am currently learning to use protractor and try to run my trial test case. I am able to open the web browser. After successfully open the URL, the test failed with error: "process exited with error code 1"

My chrome version: Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Protractor version: 5.4.2
Webdriver version: 12.1.1

Using the same method that I am able to get success result from this page https://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial , I modify to enter my URL and element. But failed.

I use name instead of model. Below is the element from my page:

```
<input _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" matinput="" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" id="mat-input-0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

I tried to do the same on google page, but also facing same result.

> // conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

> // spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('enter search word in google search field', function() {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/');
    element(by.name('q')).sendKeys('protractor for angular testing');
    browser.sleep('10000');
   });
});
```

I expect to be able to enter the string 'protractor for angular testing' in the search field successfully.

Comment: Protractor will (and should) exit with error code 1 when a test fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protractor will (and should) exit with error code 1 when a test fails. You should catch this if you would like to do something else.

and do this your error will get resolved

```
 describe('Protractor Demo App', function() { 
 it('enter search word in google search field', function() { 

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
 browser.get('https://www.google.com/'); 
 element(by.name('q')).sendKeys('protractor for angular testing');
  browser.sleep('10000');
 });
});
```

you have to enable angular wait to `true or false` accordingly

Comment: @Hafizan let me know if this didnt helped you

Comment: Hi Rao, it helps. I can now send the string to the google search field. I will try it out at my application later and see if it works as well.

Comment: Hi. Tested it with my application and it works too. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: But when trying at my application, it returns with Failures:
1) 
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
        at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
        at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)

Comment: 1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 32.542 seconds

[15:39:34] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:39:34] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[15:39:34] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[15:39:34] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Comment: Two ways you can resolve this is by by setting Jasmine time out to max and the best way is `async await`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one to use the webdriver. remove `selenium address` in your `config` and add the below one

```
exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,
    };
```

Hope it helps you.

And if you are using protractor for non-angular application refer here
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f52438549f7d920da1600199feaf58059d6fd692/spec/withLoginConf.js